# Is this probabilistic balls-and-bins problem well-defined and is my solution correct?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, mathematical-modeling, balls-in-bins

*Problem definition:*

There are $n$ bins, labeled with $1, 2, \ldots, n$. Let $X_i$ be a random
variable denoting the number of balls contained in the $i$-th bin. The
collection of random variables $X_i$ is independent and identically distributed,
with the same probability distribution (in which $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are two different positive integers)

$$
  p_x = \mathbb{P}(X_i = x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
    \frac{1}{2} \big( 1 + (\frac{\lambda}{\mu + \lambda})^2 \big)& \textrm{if
    $x = 0$}
    \\
    \frac{(2 \lambda + \mu)^2}{2(\mu + \lambda)^2} \cdot (\frac{1}{2}
    \frac{\mu}{\mu + \lambda})^{x}& \textrm{if $x \geq 1$}\\
  \end{array} \right.
$$

> Problem: What is the probability of the event, denoted $E_{n,m}$, that there are
>   in total $m$ balls in these $n$ bins?

---

*My solution:*

For convenience, we write
$$
  r \triangleq \frac{(2 \lambda + \mu)^2}{2(\mu + \lambda)^2} \textrm{ and } s
  \triangleq \frac{1}{2} \frac{\mu}{\mu + \lambda}.
$$

There are two cases according to whether there are empty bins.

- *There are no empty bins (denoted as an event $E_{\forall X_i > 0}$).*

  In this case, we are partitioning integer $m$ into a sum of $n$ *positive* integers.
  There are ${m-1 \choose n-1}$ ways of partitions. For each partition

  $$
      m = m_1 + m_2 + \cdots + m_n \quad (m_i > 0, 1 \le i \le n),
    $$

  the probability that the $i$-th bin contains $m_i$ balls is

  $$
      (r \cdot s^{m_1}) (r \cdot s^{m_2}) \cdots (r \cdot s^{m_n}) = r^n s^m
    $$

  Thus, the probability of the case there are no empty bins is

  $$
      \mathbb{P}(E_{\forall X_i > 0}) = {m-1 \choose n-1} r^n s^m
    $$
- *There exist empty bins (denoted as an event $E_{\exists X_i = 0}$)*.

  Suppose there are $k$ empty bins. In this case, we are partitioning integer
  $m$ into a sum of $n$ integers such that $k$ of them are 0 and $n-k$ of
  them are positive. There are ${n \choose k} {m-1 \choose n-k-1}$ ways of
  partitions. For each partition

  $$
      m = m_1 + m_2 + \cdots + m_n \quad (\textrm{exactly } k \textrm{ of them
      are } 0),
    $$

  the probability that the $i$-th bin contains $m_i$ balls is

  $$
      p_0^{k} \cdot r^{n-k} \cdot s^{m}
    $$

  Thus, the probability of the case there exist empty bins is

  $$
      \mathbb{P}(E_{\exists X_i = 0}) = \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} {n \choose k} {m-1
      \choose n-k-1} p_0^{k} r^{n-k} s^{m}
    $$

Combining these two cases together, it yields

\begin{align*}
  \mathbb{P}(E_{n,m}) &= \mathbb{P} (E_{\forall X_i > 0}) + \mathbb{P}
  (E_{\exists X_i = 0})  \\
   &= {m-1 \choose n-1} r^n s^m + \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} {n \choose k} {m-1 \choose n-k-1}    p_0^{k} r^{n-k}
   s^{m}
\end{align*}

---

*My questions:*

This probabilistic (balls-and-bins) model is an abstraction of a problem I am working on. Therefore, I am wondering

> Questions: Is this probability problem well-defined and is my solution correct?

Specifically,

- For *well-defined*, did I miss some conditions or assumptions for the calculation of $\mathbb{P}(E_{n,m})$?
- For *correctness*, as a probability distribution, it is necessarily that 
  $\sum_{m=0}^{m=\infty} \mathbb{P}(E_{n,m}) = 1$. Is this correct?

**EDIT:** Using *Mathematica*, it does sum to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to distinguish the two cases, the $E_{\forall X_i > 0}) $ is just a particular case of the other (as the final formula shows). Further, you should restrict the last sum to $n-1$

A slightly simpler derivation:

First: assume, $m>0$; given a set of $c>0$ particular cells, the probability that all them are non-empty and that they sum $m$ is given (as you deduced) as the sum over all [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) (ordered non-empty partitions) of $m$ into $c$ parts of the (here constant) probability $r^c s^m$.

Let $C$ be the number of non-empty cells. Then

$$P(E_{n,m})=\sum_{c=1}^{n} P(E_{n,m} ,C=c)$$

$$ P(E_{n,m} ,C=c) = {n \choose c} p_0^{n-c} {m-1 \choose c-1} r^c s^m $$

Or, changing $k=n-c$:

$$P(E_{n,m})=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} {n \choose k} p_0^{k} {m-1 \choose n-k-1} r^{n-k} s^m$$

For the special case $m=0$, $P(E_{n,0})=p_0^n$.